# The expression: $-5^2$

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

A few people I met were debating over if $-5^2 = 25$ or $-25$.

From my experience, we assume operator precedence and get $-25.$
People are telling me however, calculators are flawed, the real answer is $25.$

Clarifying note, the expression is merely:
$-5^2$
nothing else. 
What would you say?

**Edit:**
I've also tried saying $f(x)=-x^2$ is a parabola that opens downwards, but this was apparently a problem with graphing calculators as well.

Comment: It is important to distinguish between $-5^2 = -25$, and $(-5)^2 = 25$.

Comment: hence why I said, the expression includes no parentheses.

Comment: For those who downvote: please specify a reason.

Comment: My comment still applies.

Comment: What does this have to do with "calculators" ?

Comment: I posted an image of google calculator saying -5^2 = -25. But several sources were linked saying calculators are wrong in this regard.

Comment: Can you show one ?

Comment: http://www.actuarialoutpost.com/actuarial_discussion_forum/showthread.php?t=276773
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200271/difference-between-squaring-a-negative-number-and-multiplying-2-equal-negative-n
http://mathhelpforum.com/calculators/187745-square-negative-number-calculator-wrong.html

Comment: This link is meaningless as long as the kind of calculator is not specified. It could be a basic 4 operations pocket calculator, a scientific one or a symbolic one. All use different precedence conventions. Also note that there exists a confusion between the negative sign $-$ (sometimes denoted $+/-$ on a key) and the subtraction operator $-$, making things highly ambiguous. Without a specific context, your question can't be answered.

Answer (score 4):

By definition of the order of operations, exponentiation takes precedence over negation. Therefore,
$$
-5^2 = (-1) \times 5 \times 5 = -25
$$
but the alternative would be
$$
(-5)^2 = \left[(-1) \times 5\right] \times \left[(-1) \times 5 \right] = 25.
$$

Comment: As I said, the expression contains no parentheses. Would the 2nd part of your answer still apply?

Comment: Since it contains no parentheses, @SzmatoPotato, technically, no, the second part does not apply. The assumption that it *does* apply is the common mistake that produces the entire controversy/debate.

Comment: They are now saying "-5 isn't a negation operation it's an interger"

Comment: I quote: "a negative is a sign, not an operator"

Comment: @SzmatoPotato If you want to treat $-5$ as an integer, the convention is to specifically write $(-5)^2=25$ for the second line and $-5^2$ to mean the first line. There are multiple ways to skin the cat, but we need to end up with the same stew afterwards whichever way you choose.

Answer (score 4):

You’re right. $-5^2$ means $-1\cdot 5^2$.

$$-5^2 = -1\cdot 5^2 = -25$$

They’re confusing it with $(-5)^2$, which means $(-5)\cdot (-5)$.

$$(-5)^2 = (-5)\cdot (-5) = +25$$

Comment: Great explanation, think this makes sense. I will hold off on marking the best answer though.

Answer (score 3):

When -5^2 is written on paper, it's assumed that it's actually (-5)^2, as in the negative was already applied to the 5 before squaring. Often times this is where the confusion comes from when typing -5^2 into a calculator is equal to -25.
The calculator is not necessarily wrong. When you type -5^2, the calculator is really calculating -(5)^2. It squares the 5 first, then it applies the negative(multiplies the equation by negative 1.) This is really what the negative sign means, multiplying the number by -1. When we teach and learn -'s though, we automatically multiply it out, since -5 and -(5) equals the same thing, which is -5. Just know that when you put a negative sign in your calculator, you're really putting **"-1x..."**, "negative one times..."

Comment: What you are saying is false.  $-5^2 = -1 \cdot 5^2$, while $(-5)^2 = (-5)(-5)$.

Answer (score 2):

Without a parentheses the negative is taken as a -1, so it would read as ${-1*5^2}$, which would equal -25. With a parentheses, it would be read as $({-5)^2}$ which equals 25.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.
Can you clarify what you mean by "With a parentheses, it would be read as −52 which equals 25."

Comment: Put the -5 inside the parentheses. it will look like (-5)^2

Comment: The way you wrote the second sentence is needlessly confusing.  You should distinguish between $-5^2$ and $(-5)^2$.

Comment: Do you get what I'm saying though?

Answer (score 2):

To properly answer you question, I need a graphing calculator. I don't have one, but I do have a scientific calculator, a CVS knock-off of a Sharp 2-line model.

I pressed the negation key "+/-", the display shows "-0". So far so good. Then I press 5 and the display changes to "-5". But then I press the $x^2$ key and then "(-5)²" goes up on the top line of the display. So this calculator has clearly understood my button pushing to mean "$(-5)^2$", not "$-(5^2)$".

Hmm... I wonder about reverse Polish... $(-5)^2$ would be $5 - 5 - \times$, while $-(5^2)$ would be $0 \, 5 \, 5 \times -$ (press Enter when you need to follow a number with another number).

If Jerry Springer got involved in this debate, I think he would cap it off saying that "Ultimately, communication among humans is subject to the vagaries of shared experiences, and in those gaps, ambiguities creep in." Or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

By the rules of precedence, in mathematical notation $-5^2=-(5^2)$, not $(-5)^2$.

For the same reason, $-5-5$ is not $(-5)(-5)$. No discussion.

---

If this concerns calculator input, the answer is not unique.

Comment: What would you say to "if you're assuming it's an operation you're bringing into question how you can ever write negative numbers"? I'm unsure of how to answer this one.

Comment: @SzmatoPotato: sorry, I can't decipher your question.

Comment: I think they mean -5 implies (-5) the integer, and I'm unsure of how to dispute this.

Comment: @SzmatoPotato: there are rules of precedence.